# Arduino if statement always true

Tags: arduino, atmega

I am creating a program for my Arduino mega with L293D Motor shield and bluetooth Module at rx pin for my arduino rc car project.

```
    #include <AFMotor.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10,11); // RX, TX

AF_DCMotor motor1(3); 
AF_DCMotor motor2(4); 

char intra = '0';
void setup()  
{
  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  motor1.setSpeed(200);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
    if(mySerial.available()>0) {
      intra = mySerial.read();
      mySerial.write(intra);
    }
   if(intra == '1'){
    up();
    }

}

void up(){

  motor1.run(FORWARD);

}
```

So the problem is basically the if statement if getting executed even when variable 'intra = 0". So resulting, the motor at the specific port is always rotating.

Also, the rx1,tx1 or rx2,tx2 or rx3,tx3 none of then are responding when i use

```
Serial1.begin(9600);
Serial1.read();
```

or so on....
it still reads from rx0,tx0 i.e. pin 1 and 0.

Comment: How do you know the statement is executed and `intra == 0`? What do you send to the serial?

Comment: Are you saying that once the motor starts moving it never stops?  Where in that code is any line that should make the motor stop?  Just because the if statement isn't true anymore doesn't mean that the processor will suddenly guess that you want the motor to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the line (in original question before it was changed)

```
if(intra = 1) {
```

This will always take the true branch. 
This error is an easy to miss C code issue.  The correct expression you wanted is:

```
if(intra == 1) {
```

Note the **two** equal signs.
One equal sign is assignment.
Two equals signs is test for equality.

A simple way to prevent this type of hard to see failure is to get in habit of typing this:

```
if(1 == intra) {
```

The if one day by mistake you type:

```
if(1 = intra) {
```

you will get an compiler error.

A second method to detect this type of error is to turn on compiler warnings.  Select the menu item File > Preferences.  In the dialog about middle down is a drop down box "Compiler warnings".  Choose "All".

The compiler will warn you about that line:

```
_yourfilename_.ino:41:11: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment 
used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
if(intra = 1) {
```

Comment: I have already tried that. If i do the the if condition is not getting executed even when i pass '1' in bluetooth. It also shows '1' in the serial monitor but the if statement does not respond

Comment: Yes, you have a second error: intra is the wrong data type.  SoftwareSerial.read() returns a char, but you defined intra as float.  Change that intra to a char.  Then for the check you would compare to '1' or 1.  You have to determine what is being sent, a binary 1 or the character 1.  If you are using a terminal program, then the comparison is '1' == intra

Comment: If i change to char then the serial monitor shows up the input but the if condition does not get execcuted...also i have updated the code.....And the input is not binary...just using 0 and 1 inputs only to test.

Comment: can you help with this?

Comment: It is inappropriate of you to change the question to change the problem.  When the question changes all answers become irrelevant.